# VueJS array returns length = 0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have created an array in my VueComponent.

When I run a console.log(myArray.length) it says "0", however if I run a console.log(myArray) it shows that the array has the expected data. Check the screenshot from console below. The first part shows myArray, the second is myArray.length (circled in red)

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3sQ9.png)

Here is my current code:

```
   Vue.component('invoice-archive', {
    data: function () {
                return {
    invoices: [],
      }
    },
    created() { 
       this.myUpdateMethod();
    },
    methods:{
      myUpdateMethod: function(){
          var $this = this;
          let data = { 'id': installationId };

          this.getAjax('myUrlHere', data).then(function (result) {  
            if(!result.length ) return; // <-- This was the problem
            $this.invoices.push(JSON.parse(result));
    console.log($this.invoices); // This shows the expected content of my array
console.log($this.invoices.length); // This shows 0
        }); 
      },
       getAjax(url, data, success) {

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

                    xhr.onload = function () {

                        resolve(this.responseText);
                    }

                    xhr.onerror = reject;

                    xhr.open('POST', url);

                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

                    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));               

                });
            },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you are resolving the promise with `this.responseText`, you are passing a string into it. You will need to convert the response to JSON first, i.e.:

```
resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
```

Since you're using VueJS, you might want to consider using axios instead of rolling your own AJAX request handler: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: My bad..I already had this, but hadn't added it to my question. Updated the question now with the code. 

The result is still the same however even with the JSON.parse() :/

Comment: @Sjobi Can you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example? Can you share what `result` actually look like? I've tested your code and it seems to work fine.